# ComponentWillMount only trigger for first time?

Tags: react-native, components, lifecycle, native-base

MainComponent:

```
<Tabs 
  initialPage={this.props.day}
  tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#5AF158' }} 
  renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTab />}>
  {this.renderTabHeader()}
</Tabs>

renderTabHeader() {
  return (
    this.props.dateArray.map((date, i) => 
      <Tab 
        key={i}
        heading={date.format('DD/MM')} 
        tabStyle={styles.tabStyling} 
        activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle} 
        textStyle={styles.tabTextStyle} 
        activeTextStyle={styles.activeTabTextStyle} 
      >
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: '#EEEEEE', flex: 1 }}>
          <Content contentDate={date.format('YYYY-MM-DD')} />
        </View>
      </Tab>
    )
  );
}
```

Content Component:

```
class Content extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Component Will Mount() ?');
    this.props.loadTransactionByDate({ date: this.props.contentDate });
  }

render() {
  return (
    <View><Text>{this.props.contentDate}</Text></View>
  );
  }
```

Basically, in MainComponent there is a collection of tabs. I've noticed something rather weird which `Content` will be mounted on the first time their tab being click or active?

Meaning for the first time, we can click on Tab index 2 and seeing the console log in `componentWillMount`, then we switch to another tab and if coming back to Tab index 2 again, `componentWillMount` will not be triggered anymore?

Comment: Not sure if I remember correctly, but your component is already mounted when you switch tabs, so it will not mount again. It will probably call componentWillUpdate(), but not componentWillMount();

Comment: Can you add the Tabs package that you're using?

Comment: @PritishVaidya: May I know what Tabs package that you're referring to as `Tabs` been included at first section of this question

Comment: @GuiHerzog: I don't think so as I've made a console log for each and every component lifecycle method in my `Content` component. Apparently these component lifecycle only being triggered on first load, once revisit the same tab again, none of these component lifecycle method will be triggered

Comment: Check here for updates on this query https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1798

Comment: This happens when you use TabNavigator. All tabs componentWillMount calls only once. But if you want to know whether component `willFocus` somewhat similar to componentWillMount. Then you can addLister  docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle

Answer (score 8):

First I would like to point out you should not use `componentWillMount` life cycle method since it has been deprecated on last minor update of React 16.3

Heres list of deprecated life cycle methods,
`(componentWillMount, componentWillReceiveProps, and componentWillUpdate).` You can read more about deprecated life cycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Secondary in your example life cycle works as expected. `componentWillMount` triggers only once since your component will be `initial rendered/mounted` only one time and that's how React works.

I would work this out with following method.

Add [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) life cycle to Content component, which will trigger when component receives new props and as well on initial mount.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  console.log('will log on props change');
  if( nextProps.contentDate !== prevState.contentDate ) {
    return { contentDate: nextProps.contentDate };
    // Notice we return plain object here to update state
  }
  return null;
  // return null when changes are not needed
}
```

This example checks that `contentDate` has changed and if so pushes it into component -state. And on render method you get it by `this.state.contentDate`.

```
render() {
  return (
    <View><Text>{this.state.contentDate}</Text></View>
  );
}
```

You could achieve similar behaviour with implementing this in `componentDidUpdate` but then you have much bigger risk to end up with infinite loops and much worse performance. But it's possible just have strong checks that data you have expected has really changed as you would expect. Then you can do `setState` and component re-renders.

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps() is defined as an instance method and will be ignored. Instead, declare it as a static method